# Importing SSL certificate in browser does not prevent the secure warning

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I have an embedded device (ESP32) that runs an HTTPS server.
I generated the certificates in this way:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout prvtkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out cacert.pem -subj "/CN=My app"
```

I'm aware this is self-signed and no authority provides a trust for it.
Hence when I try to connect to the server I got the expected warning in the browser, asking me to accept the certificate anyway.

Then I installed the `cacert.pem` to my browser (tried with Firefox on desktop and also on an Android device). The certificate was correctly imported but still the browsers show the warning. In detail Firefox says:

> MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY

Did I miss anything? What is the purpose of installing the certificate in the browser if it still ask for a security concern?

Comment: *"show the warning"* - what warning do you get exactly? What explanation do the details or advanced information to the warning give?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich question updated

Comment: Just [google this error](https://www.google.com/search?q=MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and you find similar questions like [Why is Firefox not trusting my self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738140/why-is-firefox-not-trusting-my-self-signed-certificate).

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers aren't interested in the `Subject`.  Instead, they need to match the URL you enter in their address bar against the `subjectAlternativeName` (SAN) extension.  Normally, a DNS Name or IP Address.

You therefore need to ensure that your certificate has an appropriate SAN entry.

You should also ensure that the `basicConstraint` extension is either missing, or if included, set to `CA:False`.

This is only relevant if you have a fixed name.  If you don't have a fixed name, then you cannot certify it. A certificate binds a public key to a known identity - a name or IP address usually. This is similar to the way humans have passports or other forms of ID. If you can't verify the person's name, the passport or ID can't be issued. Similarly, if you can't verify the hostname or IP, an X.509 certificate can't be issued. There are a few alternatives to DNS/IP in the standard (RFC 5280) but I doubt they'll help here. Basically, if you don't know what you're certifying, you can't certify it!

A commercial CA will be stricter, in that the name which you bind to your public key must be verifiable from the public Internet.  That normally means a public DNS name.  That is, while you could self-sign certificates within a private namespace (such as `<hostname>.fritz.box` or `<hostname>.mark.test`) a public CA will not be able to verify these names, therefore won't issue certificates with them.

Comment: I cannot use the IP address since it's assigned by DHCP. I know only the hostname in advance (but I've just tested it as SAN and it does not work). To match the URL I should use, say, `<hostname>.fritz.box` in my scenario, but again it depends on the specific installation.

Comment: I apologize, but what is the DNS name in this context, exactly?

Comment: `<hostname>.fritz.box` is not acceptable since I don't know it in advance (it depends on the specific router of the final user). And also `<hostname>` is not valid because the browser cannot resolve it.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Last question: is this valid only for self-signed certificates? I mean, if I buy "real" certificates (recognized by stock browsers) and deploy them into the devices, it would change anything?